# Java stream multiple filter problem on nested lists?

Tags: java, stream, java-stream, nested-lists, flatmap

I have the following stream that works without any problem:

```
final List<ProductCategoryDTO> productCategoryList = productCategoryService
                .findAllByMenu(menuUuid)
                .stream()
                .filter(category -> !category.getProductList().isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I just want to add another filter:

```
final List<ProductCategoryDTO> productCategoryList = productCategoryService
                .findAllByMenu(menuUuid)
                .stream()
                .filter(category -> !category.getProductList().isEmpty())
                .flatMap(product -> product.getProductList().stream())
                .filter(menu -> !menu.getMenuItemProperties().isDisabled())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But it throws required type is `List<ProductCategoryDTO>` and returned type is `List<MenuItemCategoryDTO>`. I also tried to use a single filter by adding `&&` condition to the original filter, but cannot perform this.

```
.filter(category -> !category.getProductList().isEmpty() 
    && category.getProductList().stream()
   .filter(p -> !p.getMenuItemProperties().isDisabled()))
```

So, what is the correct usage for this situation? There is a product list in productCategoryList and I need to filter based on `menuItemProperties().isDisabled()` property. Any idea?

**Update:**

```
public class ProductCategoryDTO {
    private UUID uuid;
    private UUID menuUuid;
    private List<MenuItemCategoryDTO> productList;
}
```

Comment: You are flat mapping to whatever `getProductList` is returning. Why do you expect the stream after flatmapping or the result list to be type of `ProductCategoryDTO` ? Please share your `ProductCategoryDTO` class and describe what the additional filter should exclude from the result you are getting by applying your first filter.

Comment: @Eritrean Thanks a lot, I added `ProductCategoryDTO`. Sorry but I have no experience on Java stream(9 filtering nested lists. Any example pls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try it like this using `mapMulti` (introduced in Java 16)

- stream the categories
- for each Product (if any exist)

  - iterate across the properties for that product
  - continue iterating until at least one is `enabled`
  - then accept that one which adds the product to the stream.
- then return a list

```
List<ProductCategoryDTO> productCategoryList = productCategoryService
        .findAllByMenu(menuUuid)
        .stream()
        .<ProductCategoryDTO>mapMulti((category, consumer)-> {
               for(Product prod : getProductList()) {
                   if (prod.getMenuItemsProperties().isDisabled()) {
                       // check next product
                       continue;
                   }
                   // at least one enabled one found so accept category
                   consumer.accept(category);
                   break;
               } 
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you want to ensure that only categories are accepted where all the properites are enabled, the you can try it like this.

```
List<ProductCategoryDTO> productCategoryList = productCategoryService
        .findAllByMenu(menuUuid)
        .stream()
        .<ProductCategoryDTO>mapMulti((category, consumer)-> {
               for(Product prod : getProductList()) {
                   if (prod.getMenuItemsProperties().isDisabled()) {
                       return;
                   }
               }
               // all are enabled so accept category
               consumer.accept(category);    
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I had made a couple of errors in this which are now (hopefully) corrected.  The first was I had to `witness` the return type of `mapMulti` with `ProductCategoryDTO`. The second was that in the second example, the `break` should be a `return`.  During another exercise I thought about this and decided to set up your class hierarchy as best as I could.  I hope this didn't cause you too many problems.